# adding a background image to a cell and the row the cell is in

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to apply a background image to both my table row and the cell.  Is this possible either through CSS, Javascript or jQuery?

```
<table>
<tr style="background:url(/images/expand_shadow-top.png) repeat-x top;">
    <td style="background:url(/images/expand_shadow-btm.png) repeat-x bottom;"></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

If it is not possible I can try some other method.  This would be ideal but it dosen't seem to work.

Comment: will these two backgrounds be the same for all 'tr' and 'td' ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible.  But your table cell contains no content and you also don't specify it's size, therefore nothing will show.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible with CSS, Javascript **and** jQuery. You just need something in your cell, line non-breaking space (`&nbsp;`). The way you were applying styles is ok (although I would suggest to stop using inline styles - maybe move them to the `<head>` section of your HTML document).

Comment: He could, if he wanted, use `table {empty-cells: show; }` to force the `table` to show empty cells, so long as a `width` and `height` (or `min-width`/`min-height`) were defined.

Comment: @David Thomas Yes, more about `empty-cells` and its support across major browsers is [here](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/empty-cells).

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible with all three, here is css and jquery :

```
<style type="text/css">

#mytable tr{background:url(/images/expand_shadow-top.png) repeat-x top;}
#mytable td{background:background:url(/images/expand_shadow-btm.png) repeat-x bottom;}

</style>
<table id="mytable">
<tr>
    <td>something&nbsp;here</td>
</tr>
</table>
<script type="text/javascript">

$('#mytable tr').css("background","url(/images/expand_shadow-top.png) repeat-x top"); 
$('#mytable td').css("background","background:background:url(/images/expand_shadow-btm.png) repeat-x bottom"); 

</script>
```